# Unable to load xml file from a absolute path

Tags: java, maven-3

There is a maven project A. Once I do mvn clean install, the project builds and the jar is available at my local repository ie 
c:\repository\com\stackoverflow\A\A.jar

A.jar contains couple of classes and xml files used by these classes

From another maven project I am invoking one of the methods in the class which uses one XML file.

Code is:

```
public File xmlFilder(String xmlAbsolutePath) {
  File f = new File(xmlAbsolutePath);
  return f;
}
```

The second project is located in my D drive. On getting the absolute path, I am getting as **\com\stackoverflow\A\res\p.xml** which is the correct absolute path.

But If I add the following code at line 3 , I am getting as follows:

```
public File xmlFilder(String xmlAbsolutePath) {

  File f = new File(xmlAbsolutePath);

  System.out.println("AbsolutePath----"+f.getAbsolutePath());  ---> D:\com\stackoverflow\A\res\p.xml

  System.out.println("getPath------------"+f.getPath());       ---> \com\stackoverflow\A\res\p.xml 

  System.out.println("exists--------------"+f.exists());       ----> false

return f;

}
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong. Why it is not picking the xml from the repository which is present in C drive.

Comment: It is not clear where your xml file is. Are you trying to load it from the jar or from the file system?

Comment: xml file is present in resources folder in A.jar. The jar is present in repository which is in C drive. Please note that I have added the dependency correctly and I am able to access the methods present in A.jar from project B correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If the A class (that is bundled in your A.jar) wants to load the xml from the jar and it tries to access it in the way shown in your first code example then it *does not access `p.xml` inside your jar*. It accesses the *file at that location*.

It is easy to test if this is your case. After your jar is created, temporarily delete `p.xml` from the file system and run A class. It will fail to load it.

When a class needs to load a resource that is bundled in a jar then it does not use `File` but the classloader.

From the names you provide, I assume that your class A is in package: `com.stackoverflow.A`
The xml file is in the package `com.stackoverflow.A.res`

All the approaches below will load a stream with your xml

```
InputStream is = null;

// Using class - relative to the class location because path does not start with "/"
is = SimpleWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("res/p.xml");

// Using class - absolute path because path starts with "/"
is = SimpleWriter.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/stackoverflow/A/res/p.xml");

// Using classloader - path is *always* absolute. Note that leading "/" is missing
is = SimpleWriter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/stackoverflow/A/res/p.xml");
```

Comment: I tried using getClass().getResource(xmlAbsolutePath);as you suggested Now code looks as follows: File f = null; try{ URL resourceFile = getClass().getResource(xmlAbsolutePath); if(resourceFile != null){ f = new File(resourceFile.toURI()); System.out.println("FILE EXISTS -----"+ f.exists()); } }catch(URISyntaxException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }return f; but on debugging the path I got it as follows:jar:file:\C:\repository\com\stackOverflow\A.jar!\com\stackOverflow\A\res‌​ources\p.xml. Do u have any idea why the "!" is present URI path which is causing my issue

Comment: I am guessing this is posted here by accident. I haven't suggested using `getResource()`. The `!` notation is normal for paths inside a jar file

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is any issue in using getResource() and also how can I remove the ! symbol so that I can actually use the code. Any idea is welcome

Comment: The reason I used getResource() is because I wanted it to be it as a File, I am making it as a File using toURI() method. Is there anything I am missing, In the above suggestions made by you, I will have it as a InputStream not as a File

Comment: If you want to load the xml from a jar, you can't have it as a `File`. I mention that in my answer. You can do the same thing from `URL` calling `url.openStream()`. What are you going to do with the xml? You will pass it to a parser probably? Parsers accept `InputStream`. If it is not clear to you how to do that, please edit your question and add the code that uses the `File` returned by your `xmlFilder()` method

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the wrong question. You probably want to know has to access `p.xml`. The best way is to put A.jar on the classpath, which you do by specifying it as a dependency in the pom.xml of "the other Maven Project".
In your code you do the following:

```
Foo.class.getResource("/thePackagePath/to/p.xml");
```

By trying to access the xml as a file, you make your project very bad portable to other systems.

Comment: I tried using getClass().getResource(xmlAbsolutePath);Now code looks as follows:                                                   File f = null;
  try{
  URL resourceFile = getClass().getResource(xmlAbsolutePath);
  if(resourceFile != null){
    f = new File(resourceFile.toURI());
    System.out.println("FILE EXISTS -----"+ f.exists());
  }
  }catch(URISyntaxException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }return f; but on debugging the path I got it as follows:jar:file:\C:\repository\com\stackOverflow\A.jar!\com\stackOverflow\A\resources\p.xml. Can anyone tel why the "!" is present URI path

Comment: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html explains the reason of the '!'