# Cannot find json file in project folder

Tags: java, eclipse

My project setup looks like this:
[image]

Now i try to reference the `report.json` file like this within the `MainFrameTest.java`:

```
Template template = new JsonTemplate(Thread.currentThread().
            getContextClassLoader().getResource("/report.json").toURI());
```

I also tried:

```
Template template = new JsonTemplate(Thread.currentThread().
        getContextClassLoader().getResource("report.json").toURI());
```

And the full path:

```
Template template = new JsonTemplate(Thread.currentThread().
        getContextClassLoader().getResource("C:/prohes/esc_print_test/report.json").toURI());
```

But i always get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at esc_print_test.MainFrameTest.<init>(MainFrameTest.java:28)
at esc_print_test.MainFrameTest.main(MainFrameTest.java:55)
```

What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is at `MainFrameTest.java` at 28 ?

Comment: In `28` there is `getContextClassLoader().getResource("/report.json").toURI()); `

Comment: first try to print the location that you are in then it could be possible to get the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to fine first current Directory then u can give the resources.

do this this will give u the current Address of folder.

```
String name = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
System.out.println("Test "+ name);
```

and then u can have file, as you have defined path.

for getting new file in that path do something like this.

```
File file = new File(name, "/"+ "yourfilename.extension");
```

hope this helps.

and well another option is

```
URI file = new File(name, "/"+ "one.text").toURI();
            System.out.println(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the json file in src folder and use directly in `getContextClassLoader().getResource("report.json")`.

**EDIT:**

I tried this in my eclipse:

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
        System.out.println("test="+Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("report.json"));
    }
```

Output:

```
test=file:/D:/liferay/BundleTomcat/workspace/springBatch/target/classes/report.json
```

Just to be sure check the report.json file is present in the target folder where the .class files are present.

Comment: After putting JSON file in src file, try this : MainFrameTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/report.json");

Comment: Also find more info on loading from src folder here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865427/load-a-file-from-src-folder-into-a-reader

Comment: I think that will not work even that is giving path of the jdk because u have use that thread