# NullPointerException when trying to display image?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception

This applet is a simple about the developer page in a website i'm  creating for a class project. I'm trying to display an image and a bio for each different JButton.
I'm having an Issue with compiling, I keep getting a NullPointerException error
on this line

`danPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pics/danSkaggs.jpg"));`

Which i'm assuming it goes null because it can't find the image based on the directory i'm giving it. However I can't understand what I can do different, I can't see any problems with how the directory is written. The directory is pics/filename.jpg and the folder is in the same package as the Java code.

Here is the full source code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Developers extends JApplet{
private JButton danButton = new JButton("Dan Skaggs");
private JButton brandonButton = new JButton("Brandon Shaw");
private JButton jamesButton = new JButton("James Simpson");
private JLabel bioLabel = new JLabel("Please click one of the buttons on the left.");
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel westPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
private ImageIcon danPic;
private ImageIcon brandonPic;
private ImageIcon jamesPic;
private JLabel dLabel; 
private JLabel bLabel; 
private JLabel sLabel; 



//This array carries the Bios of the group project members
String[] bio = new String[]{"Insert Bio",
    "Insert Bio",
    "Insert Bio"};


public Developers(){
    mainPanel.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    westPanel.add(danButton);
    westPanel.add(brandonButton);
    westPanel.add(jamesButton);


    centerPanel.add(bioLabel);
    mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    danButton.addActionListener(new Handler());
    brandonButton.addActionListener(new Handler());
    jamesButton.addActionListener(new Handler());

    danPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pics/danSkaggs.jpg"));
    brandonPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pics/brandonShaw.jpg"));
    jamesPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pics/jamesSimpson.jpg"));

    dLabel = new JLabel (danPic);
    bLabel = new JLabel (brandonPic);
    sLabel = new JLabel (jamesPic);
    centerPanel.add(dLabel);
    add(mainPanel);
}


private class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource()== danButton){
            bioLabel.setText(bio[0]);
            centerPanel.add(dLabel);
        }
        else if(event.getSource()== brandonButton){
            bioLabel.setText(bio[1]);
            centerPanel.add(bLabel);
        }
        else if(event.getSource()== jamesButton){
            bioLabel.setText(bio[2]);       
            centerPanel.add(bLabel);
        }
    }
}//end Handler class
}//end Developer class
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) instead, it will give the `exception` you can caught and process accordingly.

Or

```
danPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pics/danSkaggs.jpg"));
```

You are missing the `/` as **pics** is package name, must use `/` to make `url` other wise **pics** will embed to the parent **dir** name to make mistake.So use (poor way)

```
danPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pics/danSkaggs.jpg"));
```

The `Exception` is on the first one because it is executed first also *change other two statements* that are getting the image.

I just tested that it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

So `getResource` is returning `null`: your path to the picture is wrong. Note that these are *relative paths* (relative to the class you fetched with `getClass`) so you are probably missing the initial slash which would make it an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

`danPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("danSkaggs.jpg"));`

This will load the image from the class path assuming `pics` directory is on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource("pics/danSkaggs.jpg")` is a relative path. If your class is at a package `com.mydomain` it expects to find the image in `/com/mydomain/pics/danSkaggs.jpg`

If the class and the image are in the same package just use `getResource("danSkaggs.jpg")`. For more details check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771919/unable-to-load-xml-file-from-a-absolute-path/17787262#17787262) sample code that demonstrates loading resources using either a class or even better its classloader.