# Unable to load an html file (from local file system) using JxBrowser

Tags: javafx, jxbrowser

Using JavaFX and Eclipse IDE, I have used the sample app from Teamdev for loading a sample file (notifications.html from my file system) but I keep getting the page not found/DNS error.

The file in question, notifications.html, is right there in the same package as the source file that invokes it as shown in the snippet below:

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(view), 700, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    browser.loadURL("notifications.html");
```

I think my issue is composing the fully qualified path and since I'm using a Mac, it is not clear to me how to do this. I have tried:

```
browser.loadURL("Users/myusername/Documents/workspace/jxBrowser/src/application/notifications.html");
```

However it did not work.

Comment: I am using JxBrowser chromium engine from Teamdev.

Comment: When you want to get a file from inside a source folder you cannot use the absolute path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771919/unable-to-load-xml-file-from-a-absolute-path/17787262#17787262

Comment: But as I mentioned in my original post, not using the full path does not work either. According to JxBrowser documentation, the browser.loadURL() method can be used to load a web page or an html file from the file system: "Same method can be used for loading a HTML file from a local file system. Instead of URL you just need to provide absolute path to HTML file. For example: browser.loadURL("C:\\path\\index.html"); but for a Mac, what would the path string look like if the html file is in Users/<username>/Documents/source folder?

Comment: Try `file:///Users/Username/Documents/.......`

Comment: Thanks - This worked as far as being able to actually loading the html file. However, the notification generated when the Show notification button is clicked does not appear - strange.

Comment: Notifications are not displayed by default in JxBrowser. You need to register your own NotificationHandler where you should show your own Notification dialog. See the following documentation: https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/NotificationHandler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `loadHtml()` instead `loadUrl()` suppose loadHtml goes to network and you try to download url from file on your pc. Read html from filesystem to String and pass it to `loadHtml()` method.

```
     InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/notifications.html");
     String html = null;
     try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         String row;
         while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
             builder.append(row);
         }
         html = builder.toString(); 
     }  catch (IOException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }

     browser.loadHTML(html);
```

for this code your html file must be in `resources` folder of your project

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. the HTML file gets loaded and displayed AND the Notification pop up works. Clicking the "Show notification" button on the page pops up the notification and clicking "Close notification" closes the dialog. Strangely though, when I use the browser.loadURL("file:///Users/username/etc/notifications.html") method the html page gets loaded and displayed as expected but the notification buttons do nothing. See my comment to Chris above. THANKS!